# I can't include VTK headers in my Qt algorithm

Tags: qt, image-processing, vtk, qmake

I am using Qt Creator and I want To do some Image Processing using VTK, so after building and installing VTK with Cmake and Visual studio...  I added the lib and bin Path in the .PRO, but when I include the headers in my algorithm it still give me that the file is not found.

this is my .PRO

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QtDCMSeriesDisplay
TEMPLATE = app



SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L/C:/Program Files (x86)/VTK/bin/\
-lQVTK\
-lvtkalglib\
-lvtkCharts\
-lvtkCommon\
-lvtkDICOMParser\
-lvtkexoIIc\
-lvtkexpat\
-lvtkFiltering\
-lvtkfreetype\
-lvtkftgl\
-lvtkGenericFiltering\
-lvtkGeovis\
-lvtkGraphics\
-lvtkhdf5_hl\
-lvtkhdf5\
-lvtkHybrid\
-lvtkImaging\
-lvtkInfovis\
-lvtkIO\
-lvtkjpeg\
-lvtklibxml2\
-lvtkmetaio\
-lvtkNetCDF_cxx\
-lvtkNetCDF\
-lvtkpng\
-lvtkproj4\
-lvtkRendering\
-lvtksqlite\
-lvtksys\
-lvtktiff\
-lvtkverdict\
-lvtkViews\
-lvtkVolumeRendering\
-lvtkWidgets\
-lvtkzlib

INCLUDEPATH+= C:/Program Files (x86)/VTK/include/vtk-8.2
```

and this my headers

[image]

This is what gives me as errors

[image: error]

Comment: Does `QMake` handle paths with spaces in them or do you need to quote them? I think you need to quote your paths.

Comment: When in doubt, just look into the generated files. You must quote the path containing spaces.